# JFreeChart BarChart - CategoryDataset - multiple values for a series within a category

Tags: jfreechart, categories, bar-chart, series

Do you know if it is possible to have a BarChart similar to the one on the image below, but with several bars for the same series in each category ?

By that, I mean to have, for instance, 3 "First", 3 "Second", and 3 "Third" bars in each category, each of these bars with a different value.

With the `DefaultCategoryDataset`, this is not possible : if you add more than one value for a series in a specific category, only the last value is taken into account.

I have also tried adding multiple values for a series with the `DefaultMultiValueCategoryDataset` class, but this does not do what I want. For instance if you do this :

```
DefaultMultiValueCategoryDataset defaultMultiValueCategoryDataset = new
DefaultMultiValueCategoryDataset();

List<Double> vals11 = Arrays.asList(8.5D, 10.9D, 12.2D);
defaultMultiValueCategoryDataset.add(vals11, "First", "Category 1");
```

you get in the first category one bar of the series "First", whose value is actually the mean of the three values 8.5, 10.9 and 12.2. I would like three separate bars instead.

I have searched for several hours and asked on JFreeChart's forums, but they are not very active, unfortunately. Thanks

[image: JFreeChart BarChart Demo]
<sub>(source: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/JFreeChartBarChartDemo.PNG))</sub>

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116036).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java persistence?  I solved this by setting the @ID annotation in the Java class on two fields.  This allowed JFreeChart to determine the products had the same name but different sizes and therefore to treat them as two separate entries.  Sorry I don't have any examples to show you, the data is somewhat confidential.